# WRG614 router; Slow Wifi, Fast Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an WRG614 wireless router.

If I use wired Ethernet my download speed is 25 mbps.
If I use wiress my download speed is only 0.4mbps.

Upload speed stays consistent at 3Mbp/s on both.

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

The WRG614 is over 8 years old now, and has an early implementation of the 'G' wireless protocol that has a maximum speed of 54mbits per second. It's never been a fast router, and most likely the wireless transmitter is weakening due to age.

If the hardware version is v8 or WW then you can install dd-wrt third party firmware, which will allow you to adjust the transmission levels. Be careful as the firmware has no protection so if you up the TX too much it will damage itself.

If yours is neither of these revisions, try a TP-LINK TL-WR740N and install openwrt. One of the best cheap routers that are excellent with openwrt.